# Why does the extrusion tool create an additional face for the selected face?

Tags: modeling, faces, normals, extrude

[image]

This is the plane I created. It is correct with the right orientation.

[image]

After I press the <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the hotkey. It generates another orientation. It is fine if I just pull it up and make a cube.

[image]

But I want to make it bigger, so I press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it up. Now the problem starts to show up.

[image]

The middle one generates 2 orientations. I tried to merge the vertices to fix the problem. But it doesn't work.

[image]

neither Recalculate normals work

[image]

Is there anyone encountered the same problem and solved it?

Comment: The middle one doesn't create two orientations. As you press _S_, you're no longer moving it up. So there are two planes (actually six, the side faces as well) lying on top of each other, one facing down, the other facing up. Think of it like the cuboid - the bottom, top and side faces are all there in the flat mesh as well, just all on the same height level. By the way, the image where you make the cuboid: red shows the inside of faces, so you've actually pulled it in the wrong direction. What is it exactly you want to achieve? A pyramid frustum or the plane just extending outwards?

Comment: And just to explain why merging and recalculating doesn't work: there is nothing to merge. You have a large square consisting of 4 vertices and a small square in the middle consisting of 4 vertices. And between them you have 4 trapezoids, each built from 2 outer and 2 inner vertices of those squares. No overlapping vertices. Recalculating doesn't work because because the faces are lying on top of each other with a thickness of 0. This means, Blender cannot decide if a face is pointed in the correct direction or if there is need of recalculating. Checking _Inside_ would simply flip them all.

Comment: Just in general: an extrusion **always** creates new geometry (not a new orientation as you said under the second screenshot). If it would just move or scale the existing geometry, it would be exactly this: moving or scaling, not extruding.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I was learning jewelry modeling from one Youtuber. He made a plane extruded and scaled it to a big plane with 4 trapezoids. Then he continued to extrude down to make a cube without deleting the overlapped face step. I didn't know that before your explanation. That was quite frustrating. But now it makes me look silly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Don't worry, if I would have been here when I was beginning with Blender I would have looked silly a lot of times. Make sure you always watch tutorials thoroughly, that's one of the biggest problems when you're starting. The thing is, after pressing E you can only do one of these things: either move the new geometry (that's working by default) or scale with S or rotate with R. As soon as you choose one of these options, the movement will be aborted (but you can get back to it by pressing G Z Z, then it will be the moving along normal Z again).

Comment: And be aware, cancelling the extrusion with right-click or Esc will not delete the newly created geometry - it will just stay in place from where it started without any movement, scaling or rotation. So if you cancel the extrusion you have to either go back with Ctrl+Z or delete or merge the new vertices, or else you will have duplicate geometry there.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I turned on the face orientation, and normal. So I can see clearly which one is canceled.

Comment: As long as you don't think it's one face with two orientations ;)

Comment: :) won't do that again. Thanks.